# In OpenRasta is it possible to Pattern match multiple key/value pairs?

Tags: .net, query-string, uri, pattern-matching, openrasta

Is it possible in OpenRasta to have a Uri pattern that allows for an array of values of the same key to be submitted and mapped to a handler method accepting an array of the query parameters.

Example: Return all the contacts named Dave Smith from a collection.

HTTP GET /contacts?filterBy=first&filterValue=Dave&filterBy=last&filterValue=Smith

With a configuration of:

What syntax would be best for the Uri string pattern matching? (Suggestions welcome)

```
ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<List<ContactResource>>()
    .AtUri("/contacts")
    .And.AtUri("/contacts?filterBy[]={filterBy}[]&filterValue[]={fv}[]") // Option 1
    .And.AtUri("/contacts?filterBy={filterBy}[]&fv={fv}[]") // Option 2
```

Would map to a Handler method of:

```
public object Get(params Filter[] filters)
{
    /*
    create a Linq Expression based on the filters using dynamic linq
    query the repository using the Linq
    */

    return Query.All<Contact>().Where(c => c.First == "Dave" && c.Last == "Smith").ToResource()
}
```

where Filter is defined by

```
public class Filter
{
    public string FilterBy { get; set; }
    public string FilterValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Scott, did you find a solution in the end? Need to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 4):

`.AtUri("/contacts?filterBy={filterby}&filterValue={filterValue}")` should happily map to

```
Post(string[] filterby, string[] filterValues)
```

That should get processed the correct way, if not it's a bug.

You can also use the object syntax if you want something a bit nicer:

```
<input name="Filter:0.FilterBy" />
<input name="Filter:1.FilterBy" />
```

and have

```
Post(IEnuemrable<Filter> filter)
```

But you will probably need to use a post for this, not a get. The usual way to solve this is to do a Post-Redirect-Get to a fully built URI, which is also nicer for caching

Comment: @serialseb Is there any better way to filter List type of resources in OpenRasta?

Comment: no because filtering is not an http concept, so baking in one way of doing it in OR would make the kind of decisions that the fx tries not to make for you.